# How to insert data into NVARCHAR2 field with plsql developer?

Tags: oracle, cjk, plsqldeveloper, nvarchar

```
Oracle version: 11gr2,
NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8MSWIN1252,
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16,
client NLS_LANG: AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252,
PL/SQL Developer version: 8.0
```

I have a table which has a NVARCHAR2 field, I try to execute INSERT statement in **PL/SQL Developer** to insert some Chinese characters, but I cannot make it work. Below is the sql I use:

```
INSERT INTO charset_test VALUES(102,N'中');
```

But it works fine when using **Oracle SQL Developer** by just setting the option `convertNcharLiterals=true`. So I wonder if there is a similar option for **PL/SQL Developer** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set client environment variable `ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE` to `TRUE` and try again.